# Probability of getting $5$ once in rolling a dice two times if...

Tags: probability

A few days a go I encoutered an event with some online game and I turned it into a problem that I cant find any like it.
Now this is how it is, my cousin was playing an online game  and she had two turns to get a $5$ in rolling a dice to win. If she got the $5$, first time she rolled the dice, she would have won and no more rolling dices. but if she didn't get the $5$, she had a second chance and if she hadn't got the $5$ again, she would have lost.

Now how much is the probability of she, winning the game?

I showed it to two mathematics teachers and they both found different answers. One said its $\frac 16+ \frac 16 = \frac 26$ and I totally disagree.
The other one said its $\frac 6{31}$ because there are total of  $31$ probabilities and we want $6$ wich I again toatally disagree.
I say it's $\frac 16 + (\frac 16 * \frac 56)$ because we want the sum of probabilities if we got 5 first time or we got five the second time.

Please give some opinions because the first one is going to give me $0$ at the end of the scemester because I told him he was wrong.

Comment: Sorry for bad english :)

Comment: you have it correct  $\frac 16 + \frac 5{36} = \frac {11}{36}$  which is slightly less than $\frac 16 +\frac16 = \frac {1}{3}$ and I have no clue where $\frac 6{31}$ is coming from.

Comment: You are correct.  Both "teachers" are incorrect.  The first incorrectly used $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)\color{red}{-P(A\cap B)}$, having ignored the last but still very significant term.  Correcting the first teacher's work would have given $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{36}$, yielding the correct answer.  The second teacher incorrectly applied $Pr(A)=\frac{|A|}{|S|}$ which is only valid if each outcome is equally likely to occur.  They used a sample space where outcomes are not equally likely.

Comment: That being said, I am not that great at analysis and am pretty horrible at algebraic topology (though I'm trying to get better), so if you were to ask me a question on one of those I'm liable to get it wrong too even if I am confident in my abilities in probability and combinatorics.  As such, I can't really fault your teachers too much if probability isn't their specific field.  In the future, you might do better asking a math teacher who specializes in the subject you want to ask about.  There are many different kinds of math afterall.

Comment: As an easy way to remember that you may not simply "add" probabilities (*without also subtracting as per inclusion-exclusion*), consider the scenario of flipping three fair coins in a row and asking what the probability is of obtaining at least one head.  The erroneous solution and incorrect logic of the first teacher would have you believe that the probability was $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$ which is *larger than one*!  This is of course impossible as probabilities are always between $0$ and $1$.  Rather, without the appropriate subtractions, this is the *expected number* of heads.

Comment: Ultimately, probability is about counting. I try to find a simple partition of the sample space and work from there. One way to do it here is to let the sample space be $5,(k,l)$ for $k=1,2,3,4,6$ and $l = 1,...,6$. Now I need to figure out the probabilities of each. The first is ${1 \over 6} $ and the others have probability ${5 \over 6}\cdot{1 \over 6}$ each. Only $5$ of the pairs are winning rolls, so the probability of winning is ${1 \over 6} + {5 \over 36}$.

Answer (score 4):

An alternate way to consider the question that you are asking (what is the probability of winning?) is taking the complement (what is the probability of losing?). So in order to lose, you have to roll the dice twice and not get $5$ both times.

\begin{align}
Prob(lose) &= Prob(\text{not rolling 5}) \ \textbf{AND} \ Prob(\text{not rolling 5})
\\
&= \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{5}{6}
\\
&= \frac{25}{36}
\end{align}

So if your probability of losing is $25/36$, then your probability of winning is the "remaining" probability, or 
$$
Prob(win) = 1 - \frac{25}{36} = \frac{11}{36}
$$

Answer (score 2):

One way is to pretend that she always rolls the die twice.
Then just count all the possibilities. The winning rolls are $(5,k)$ for $k=1,...,6$ and $(k,5)$ for $k=1,...,4,6$.

There are a total of $6+5=11$ winning rolls and a total of $36$ rolls total.