# How many times do you get "k" face of a die after n rolls?

Tags: probability, dice

If I ask how many times will I get a five (face not sum) in two rolls the answer is 11 of the 36 combinations will contain a five.

What is the formula to calculate the 11 rolls which include a five? For two rolls you can list all 36 combinations and count them? But if it is 6, 7, or 8 rolls that is quite a bit of combinations to list.

This is somewhat similar to the following post:
[Probability of getting $5$ once in rolling a dice two times if...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741620/probability-of-getting-5-once-in-rolling-a-dice-two-times-if/3908836#3908836)

One formula used was where you take the complement, ex 1 - (5/6)^n where n is the number of rolls.

But if the question is how many times will you roll a 5 in 8 rolls, what formula gives you that value?  What formula gives you just the numerator?  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The basic formula you need is the binomial distribution.  The probability that you will get exactly  $k$ fives in $n$ rolls is given by $\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, where $p=\frac{1}{6}$ is the probability of getting a five on one roll.